# Minha sessão não está sendo destruída -PHP-

Tags: php, html, session

Eu tenho o seguinte código numa página de usuraiosessao:

```
  public static function destruirSessao() {
     if (isset($_SESSION)) {
        session_start();
        unset($_SESSION["codigo"]);
        unset($_SESSION["nome"]);
        session_destroy();
       }

  }
```

na pagina da index.php:

```
if (!thread::getUsuarioAtivo()) {
 header("location: login.php");
 } else {
 ?>
   Código HTML/ conteúdo da página
 <?php } ?>
```

Mesmo definindo o Session_destroy, a mesma ainda permanece,e, então eu sou capaz de digitar o url: index.php e entrar na sessão da ultima pessoa, como posso resolver? há algum erro de lógica no código?

O link de Logout é esta na pagina index:

```
     <a href="endSess.php?act=logout" ></a>
```

que chama uma outra pagina que faz o logout, essa pagina de logout tem o código

```
      $verif = $_GET['act'];
        if ($verif == "logout") {
        thread::destruirSessao();         
        header('Location: login.php');
      }
```

Comment: Uai, onde você está chamando a destruir sessão?

Comment: Ah sim, tem um botão na página Index que chama uma pagina php que é de logout, e tem o codigo thread::destruirSessao();

Comment: Coloque o código desse botão por favor?

Comment: Edita sua pergunta, assim fica mais fácil

Comment: Era exatamente isso, dei um session_start(); na função destruirSessao(); e deu certo :D, Obrigado! Gabriel Carvalho! e ao outro Gabriel Falieri também! :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Temos um erro de lógica aí. Veja que primeiro você verifica se a sessão existe para depois inicializá-la. Como você não a iniciou, ela nunca vai entrar no IF para ser destruída. Coloque o session_start() fora do IF e poste o resultado, por favor.

```
public static function destruirSessao() {
   session_start();
   if (isset($_SESSION)) {
       unset($_SESSION["codigo"]);
       unset($_SESSION["nome"]);
       session_destroy();
   }
}
```

Comment: Sim, exatamente isso, preciso inciá-la antes, deu certo aqui, era realmente isso! Muitíssimo obrigado!